# Jquery dynamically add textarea and monitor the input event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I used rails4 and Jquery-rails-atwho.

when I use Jquery to dynamically  add a

`<textara id="textareaId" ></textarea>`

to the html, and then I want to use the `atwho` function ,the codes like this:

```
$("textarea#textareaId").atwho({at:"@",'data':['abbc','udask']})
```

But it doesn't work , then I run this

`$("textarea#textareaId").atwho({at:"@",'data':['abbc','udask']})`

in the `Chrome console`, it works good , This is for why ? And how to rewrite the codes? Thanks so much!

Comment: your javascript is not loading, can you show more code? also `<textara id="textareaId" ></textarea> ` has spell mistake it should be `textarea`

Comment: please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.  But it sounds like you run the initialisation code at the wrong time

Comment: @RaviMariya @Pete , Thanks , In fact, I used the `editor.md`, and the `textarea` add by the `codeMirror.min.js`, I had solve this problem by add a `onkeypress=atUsers(event)` function in the `codeMirror.min.js  ` and it works ,maybe it a stupid method....